# Spring mvc: css does not work when adding slash at the end of URL

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, url

I am new to Spring MVC and i am having a problem with CSS. When the URL ends with slash CSS does not work. 
link goes like this
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.css">`

 mvc:resources mapping
`<mvc:resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/WEB-INF/themes/"/>` 
and requestMapping goes like this

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView loginPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");

    return model;
}
```

So the problem is when i enter a URL like `../login` the css loads normally, but when i enter `../login/` with ending slash, then the css does not load.
Well there are many similar questions in here, but none of them is for Spring MVC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.css">
```

try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/style.css">
```

When you use `href="themes/style.css"` then for url like: `.../login/` the request url for css file looks like:

```
.../login/themes/style.css
```

which is incorrect. When you use `href="/themes/style.css"` then it always should result with:

```
.../themes/style.css
```

**Update:**

If it is jsp page, then add 
`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` on top of the page
and change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.css">
```

into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/themes/style.css" />">
```

Comment: in this case CSS stops loading  for `../login` too.

Answer (score 1):

it will work 100%

step 1

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/assets/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

setp   2

```
<spring:url var="css" value="/resources/css/"/>
<spring:url var="js" value="/resources/js/"/>

<spring:url var="image" value="/resources/image/"/>
```

add a slash after value

step 3

add your style sheet like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="${css}/common/bootstrap.min.css">
```