# Java Spring JS-CSS Not Found

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I have a litte weird problem with java spring mvc. When user wants to go "localhost:8080/admin" everything works fine but when user wants to go "localhost:8080/admin/create", all CSS and JS files will be missing.

## ADMIN CONTROLLER

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

    @RequestMapping(path="")
    public String index(){
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String create(){
        return "create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String description,@RequestParam int personQuantity, @RequestParam String lastApp) {

        Job newJob = new Job();
        newJob.setJobTitle(title);
        newJob.setJobDescription(description);
        newJob.setNumberOfPersonToHire(personQuantity);
        newJob.setLastApplicationDate(lastApp);

        jobService.create(newJob);
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

## WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Kodgemisi-HR-Application-master</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: /admin]

[image: /admin/create]

[image: File Order]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
<link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ADD / to paths of js and css which written inside the html

[Spring mvc: css does not work when adding slash at the end of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116829/spring-mvc-css-does-not-work-when-adding-slash-at-the-end-of-url)